# Problems with nvidia proprietary drivers and control center

Tags: drivers, unity, 16.04, nvidia, system-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with an MSI GTX 970, and I have two monitors. I read up on how to make it work, and learned that I'd have to use the proprietary drivers, so I changed the drivers, and the system settings wouldn't open. I tried going to the terminal and running unity-control-center, and was met with:

> (unity-control-center:21126): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion >'string != NULL' failed
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How can I fix this? I had it working just fine before, but I had to reinstall for unrelated issues.

Comment: Try using the following: strace -e open gnome-control-center. Post output here.